# How to 301 redirect URL's with "index.php?" in a path?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am trying to redirect old URLs that look like this:
mysite.com/index.php?dispatch=products.view&product_id=30176
to new URL's that are SEO friendly and look like - mysite.com/category/product

I am using CS-Cart 4.3.1 with SEO add-on enabled, and when I have imported all the products and categories the URLs were automatically changed.

This add-on has 301 redirect functionality in admin, which enables me to create 301 redirects manually. However, something is wrong and it doesn't work with redirects that have "index.php?" in a path to start with.

I have tried redirecting old URLs without "index.php?" in a path - like:
 "dispatch=products.view&product_id=30176" to "mysite.com/category/product" and it works, page is being redirected. But this is not the correct URL that is indexed by Google and need redirecting.

I suspect the issue is somewhere in Rewrite Conditions or Rewrite Rules on htaccess file that were created by system upon activation of SEO add-on.

This is how it looks like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
Options -MultiViews

RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^api/(.*)$ [or]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .*/api/(.*)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .*api/(.*)$ api.php?_d=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(png|gif|ico|swf|jpe?g|js|css|ttf|svg|eot|woff|yml|xml)$ [or]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} store_closed.html$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*?)\/(.*)$ $2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

If anybody can think of a reason why the redirects are not working when "index.php?" is included in a path, I would greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: How does this URL `mysite.com/index.php?dispatch=products.view&product_id=30176` correlate to `mysite.com/category/product`? I mean do all the old URL's redirect to the same SEO link or does it change. Please provide a proper example and not a generic one or it's more difficult to help.

Comment: @PanamaJack - none of the old URLs that are like (http://example.com/index.php?dispatch=products.view&product_id=30176) are being redirected. All of the URLs have automatically changed to SEO firendly URLs after I have imported CSV file into new e-commerce store with SEO add-on enabled. Here is example:

Comment: @PanamaJack - none of the old URLs are being redirected. Here is example: [link] http://www.asia-link.com.au/index.php?dispatch=products.view&product_id=30176 should redirect to http://www.asia-link.com.au/chinese-medicine/patches/salonpas-analgesic-plasters/ but it doesn't - it gets 404. If I try to create 301 redirect as (http://www.asia-link.com.au/dispatch=products.view&product_id=30176) without "index.php?" - it works, it is being redirected to correct product. How do I get it working with "index.php?" included?

Answer (score 1):

The built-in "301 redirects" feature does not support non-seo friendly URLs as old URL parameter. It means that you cannot use "index.php?dispatch=products.view&product_id=30176", but you can use "old_website_category/old_website_product" one.

To realize what you want, please add 301 redirects to the .htaccess file. E.g.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^product_id=30176$
RewriteRule ^/?index\.php$ http://example.com/category/product? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: The problem is finally solved. Sergey from cs-market has installed his "301 Redirects" add-on, which works perfectly and redirects old URL's.